How to select an element which is fully covered by another in the Layout Inspector?
This seems like it should be trivial to google, but I haven't found anything. My app has a lot of (usually) invisible elements, including one that covers the entire screen. As such I can't click on any other element in the Layout Inspector without going into 3D mode and rotating the layout until the given element is uncovered.
I've tried going right clicking on the big invisible element and disabling it, but there's no option to do that.
I can of course select my element from the component tree, but I would prefer to be able to click directly on the image.
